# Azure dataflow activity with queued status for hours

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have my Azure data flow activity setted up.

it fetches the rows quickly from the source, but then when it comes to process the rows by spark cluster it takes ages for a small sample like 10k rows. this dataset has about 40 columns.

I cannot conceive a reason why it takes so long. The process stays blocked in that queued state and I have no clue of what's going on.

The activity is using memory optimized, and 8 Cores in settings and I'm with the default IR that strangely has general purpose and 4 cores greyed out.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this before - I would try using General Purpose 8 cores first. If that doesn't help, you'll want to put in a support ticket.

Comment: @JoelCochran I was able of making it work. I've created a new Integration Runtime with Memory Optimized and 8 Cores, and stop using the default integration runtime for dataflow. it ended up working :D Now I have bottleneck on the database on some occations :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a new Azure Integration Runtime Using Memory Optimized 8 cores compute type.**

Check [How to create and configure Azure Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory).

In step 5, fill the required **compute type** details as shown below and click on create. Use this IR to run your pipeline.

[image]